# unsure of reasoning behind a "shortcut" method to solve $(15y+24)^2 = 12(20y^2 +64y +51)$

Tags: quadratics

We are able to solve this problem by expanding, however, I've seen a shortcut method but I'm not sure how this is done. (perhaps comparing coefficients)

The shortcut method used is:

$(15+24)^2=12∗51−24^2$ <- how does this work?

$(15+24)^2=36$

$(15y+24)$ = $+6$ or $-6$

$y$ = $-2$ or $-1.2$ which gives a correct answer

Anyone could explain the shortcut method used? Why subtract $24^2$ from $12*51$? This method completely ignores the terms $20y^2$ and $64y$, but it works for many other quadratics, so I believe there must be some sort of reasoning behind this.

(I'm not looking for answers to solve this problem but possibly an explanation for the method stated)

Comment: $(-15y-24)^2=(15y+24)^2=9(5y+8)^2$

Comment: You can divide both sides by $3$.

Comment: How is this an improvement over your previous (now closed) question?

Comment: I tried to make it clearer. This method works for all sorts of quadratics but it seemed like no one could grasp the concept behind this shortcut method which could save lots of time in problem solving.

Comment: What do you mean with "all sorts of quadratic"? I doubt that. But maybe quadratics where LHS and RHS have same vertex...

Answer (score 2):

Although, this is not a well posed question and there absolutly nothing fancy about this so called "method", I will nevertheless answer it just to show you that in math nothing comes for free. If you have a "method" where two coefficients can be dropped there have to be heavy assumptions! Lets get to it:
For $A\neq0$ we have
$$
(Ay+B)^2=Cy^2+Dy+E\\
=\frac{C}{A^2}(Ay+B)^2- \frac{2CB}{A}y-\frac{CB^2}{A^2}+ Dy+ E 
$$
Now if $D= \frac{2CB}{A}$ and ${A^2\neq C}$ this simplifies to
$$
(Ay+B)^2=\frac{C}{A^2}(Ay+B)^2-\frac{CB^2}{A^2}+ E \\
\Leftrightarrow (1-\frac{C}{A^2})(Ay+B)^2=-\frac{CB^2}{A^2}+ E\\
\Leftrightarrow (A^2-C)(Ay+B)^2=-CB^2+ EA^2\\
\Leftrightarrow (Ay+B)^2=\frac{EA^2-CB^2}{A^2-C}\\
$$
Now if we further assume that $E=B^2 (2-\tfrac{A^2}{C})$ we miraculously (yes, that's sarcasm) end up with
$$
(Ay+B)^2=E-B^2.
$$

So to summarize, this "methods" works only if
$$
A\neq0\\
D= \frac{2CB}{A}\\
{A^2\neq C}\\
E=B^2 (2-\tfrac{A^2}{C})
$$